# How can I dynamically build a Java classpath in Perl?

Tags: java, perl

For Example in shell script:

```
_CLASSPATH =.
for jar in lib/*.jar
do
    _CLASSPATH=${_CLASSPATH}:${jar}
done
```

How can I dynamically build a Java classpath in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always with Perl, there's more than one way to do it, but one compact way is this:

```
$_CLASSPATH = join(":", ".", glob("lib/*.jar"));
```

If you want to set an environment variable you may need to make that:

```
$ENV{_CLASSPATH} = join(":", ".", glob("lib/*.jar"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $_CLASSPATH = join(":", ".", glob("lib/*.jar"));
$ENV{CLASSPATH} = $_CLASSPATH;
```

NOTE: If you're in a web server environment, especially one that has shared Perl interpreter like mod_perl, always localize your `$ENV{}` assignments to avoid unpleasantness: `local $ENV{CLASSPATH}=$_CLASSPATH;`

Comment: Ehh... didn't notice... I'm usually never using "." in CLASSPATH so didn't realize it was there. Thx

Answer (score -1):

Not Perl code (no code = no bugs :) but doesn't

```
export CLASSPATH=.:lib/*
```

work? In my bash script that starts Java app I set this and app can "see" all .jars I want, but you can set it "globally":

```
mn@test:~# export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jars/*
mn@test:~# echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/local/jars/*
mn@test:~# ls /usr/local/jars/*.jar
/usr/local/jars/activation.jar ...

mn@test:/home# cat show_cp.java
public class show_cp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path", "."));
        }
}

mn@test:/home# java show_cp
.:/usr/local/jars/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar:/usr/local/jars/RmiJdbc.jar:/usr/local/...
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can use wildcards in CLASSPATH as described in [Setting the class path](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

---

And Perl code to join file names:

```
my @files = glob "/jars/*.jar";
my $cp = join(":", @files);
print($cp)
```

Comment: -1 for untested code (specifically: the shell code) where it is trivial to try.

Comment: Can you please give more info what is untested? My Java apps works with `export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jars/*`, so I asked if similar setting work in asker environment.

Comment: `_CLASSPATH=.:lib/*jar`, when interpreted by the shell, does not do what you think it does. It will not be in accord with the result from the code in joe's question. (Hint: the `:` seperators are important, you indeed pay attention to them in the Perl answer, why not in the shell answer, too?) By formulating your answer as a question you even admit to not having it tested. Simply trying your code before you post can save you the trouble.

Comment: No, my Java apps work from bash on Linux with `export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jars/*`. On Windows I use .bat with `SET CLASSPATH=.;c:/jars/*`. I think this is handled by Java environment because with such setting my Java application report classpath with (Windows example): `class path: C:\test\test;C:\jars\xmlParserAPIs.jar;C:\jars\activation.jar`. By formulating question I showed that it works for my, with my environment. Other versions of JDK can work differently then version I use. In my  Java env you can use wildcards in CLASSPATH and it works.

Comment: OK. I edited answer and changed `_CLASSPATH=.:lib/*jar` -> `export CLASSPATH=.:lib/*` (jar part was not necessary)

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$CP = '.';
foreach(<lib/*.jar>) {
  $CP .= ":$_";
}
$ENV{'_CLASSPATH'} = $CP;
```